Why do we say "commit" a crime?
How did the word "commit" become so associated with performing a criminal act ("he committed a crime", "she committed a robbery" - also generally applies to errors, blunders and similar negatives), and why isn't it used that way for anything else? We don't say, for example, "he committed an act of philanthropy" or "she committed a medical procedure" to the same extent, if at all?

There is the other sense, to commit to/commit oneself to a course of action. But 'commit + DO' where the DO refers to an act is only used for errors, sin, crimes etc.

Indeed. And, of relevance: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/100740/473213

'Commit' in the sense of doing something which cannot be undone is particularly suited to sins and crimes!

@Dan surely, equally true of acts of kindness and good deeds (and we do say "I commit to improving my ways" etc)? Also, crimes can be aquitted, or "resolved" through punishment, sins can be repented of, apologies can be accepted.

There's frequently a legal distinction between planning a crime and performing a crime, with the latter described as committing the crime (perhaps an abbreviation for "committing to carry out the planned crime" -- though this is not entirely satisfactory as it's possible to commit an unplanned crime as well).  This distinction is not generally useful in other contexts (except databases).

You can also commit something to memory or to paper/writing/the written word. And of course, more recently, you can commit versions of software (files) to repositories like Github. But those aren’t acts, as Edwin points out. The only act I can think of where commit sounds fairly natural is ‘commit an act of kindness’.

@RabbiKaii - commit in the sense of resolve to do something is in the nature of an aspiration: with a fair wind, determination and a bit of luck perhaps this kind of commitment will come to pass.

See also the following extract for the different meanings and usages  of commit: “English language has words that we use so commonly that we do not even realize that they are homonyms (words with same spelling and pronunciation but different meanings). “Commit” is one of them.” https://www.thenews.com.pk/magazine/us/189751-ETYMOLOGY

Ah!  So it's a homonym !

@user66974 that would appear to be the actual answer to the questions, perhaps paste it in as an answer?

For the computer nerds: git commit murder

commit a crime means to carry out a crime. BUT commit to something is another meaning. It means to promise to fulfil some thing or other.

@Fattie indeed, why won't they commit it to an answer

it gets better :)

Apparently the sense is derived from a usage common in Latin:
Commit

The evolution of the modern range of meanings in English is not entirely clear. The sense of "perpetrate (a crime), do, perform (especially something reprehensible)" was ancient in Latin; in English it is attested from mid-15c.

(Etymonline)

Per the MED, the verb committen is attested from the mid 15th c. with the nouns "offense" and "false cause" and "exorbitance" and "confederacy" but not with the noun crime, though that noun is attested 75 years earlier, but with the verbs do and wrought. It looks as though "commit a crime" is an early modern English development.

The fact that commit has had the sense of 'do, perform' does not answer the question, which is why we use it only for doing/performing bad acts and never say that somebody, e.g. 'committed an act of philanthropy', even though it is possible to do/perform acts of philanthropy. As for perpetrate the same question can be asked about it as about commit: why do we use it only for bad acts.

I am puzzled by what Etymonline says here about "especially something reprehensible".  I have looked at the word in the Lewis and Short Latin Dictionary.  The word itself combines 'mitto' (I send) with the prepositional prefix cum (meaning 'with' or 'together').  Its most common use seems to relate to things 'done together', especially battles.  There is 'conspiracy' (whispering together).  Aren't compounds, even anglo-saxon ones, often a bit odd?  For example, how do 'withhold' and 'withstand' work?

The Merriam-Webster dictionary's first definition of the word "commit" is

"to carry into action deliberately : PERPETRATE".

So we generally say "commit a crime" to state that they did it deliberately. You can accidentally break the law, which may end up with the same legal response, but to "commit a crime" implies intent.
It may be that your speedometer was miscalibrated so that you didn't know you were going over the speed limit, but it's pretty hard to say that you didn't know it was a crime to break into a jewelry store and steal all the diamonds.
There is also the legal definition of "committed a crime", which not only shows intent to break the law, but also the action of actually breaking the law.

Committed Crime
A truly committed crime needs the following elements:

Evidence of intent to commit a crime
Evidence of planning for the offense
Evidence that direct actions were taken to commit the crime


www.attorneybailey.com
It's very likely that the average use of "commit a crime" is simply a colloquial use of the legal term, although it would probably be hard to determine which version came first, the legal term or the common term.
